# AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'Timedelta'

Tags: python, raspberry-pi

I am new to coding in general and have been using a raspberry pi along with my macbook pro as a test bench for my python creations.

My most recent project was to run a python program every 5 minutes which uses a DH11 sensor to measure the temperature and humidity to a csv file.

I was then attempting to use Bokeh with Pandas to retrieve and plot the data every 10 minutes and generate a html file which could then be hosted on a web file.

This in practice worked perfectly on my laptop however when moving over to my raspberry pi the python program plotting the data returned this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "DataAnalysis.py", line 2, in <module>
  from bokeh.plotting import figure, output_file, show
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/bokeh/plotting/__init__.py", 
line 2, in <module>
    from ..document import Document; Document
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/bokeh/document.py", line 28, 
in <module>
    from .core.json_encoder import serialize_json
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/bokeh/core/json_encoder.py", 
line 49, in <module>
    from ..util.serialization import convert_datetime_type, 
is_datetime_type, transform_series, transform_array
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/bokeh/util/serialization.py", 
line 55, in <module>
    DATETIME_TYPES.add(pd.Timedelta)
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'Timedelta'
```

Running Python 2.7, Bokeh 0.12.6

File DataAnlysis.py:

```
import pandas
from bokeh.plotting import figure, output_file
import time
import datetime

data = pandas.read_csv("http://antondubek.hopto.org/dataFile.csv", 
parse_dates = ["Time"])

p = figure(plot_width = 500, plot_height = 250, x_axis_type = 'datetime', 
responsive = True)

p.line(data["Time"], data["Humidity"], color = "Blue", alpha = 0.5)
p.circle(data["Time"], data["Humidity"], size = 5, color = "Blue")

p.line(data["Time"], data["Temperature"], color = "Red", alpha = 0.5)
p.circle(data["Time"], data["Temperature"], size = 5, color = "Red")

output_file("/var/www/html/TempReadings.html")
```

I have searched the web as best I can, uninstalled bokeh and reinstalled it both using pip still with no luck.

Any help would be appreciated.

**Edit: For anyone currently attempting anything similar, Raspian Jessie armhf (Raspberry Pi 2) currently only supports up to Pandas 0.14 and therefore has no datetime object. Have not currently found a workaround for this project.**

Comment: What version of pandas are you using? according to https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/timedeltas.html `pd.Timedelta` was added in 0.15

Comment: Removed `bokeh` tag, this is a question about Pandas. (You probably need to update)

Comment: Thank you both, Pandas is encountering an error when updating but will look into that now, think you are correct in it needing an update past 0.15 (Currently 0.14)

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo pip install pandas --upgrade
```